# Setting a user's role in WordPress: Is the 'role' string case sensitive?

Tags: php, wordpress

When setting a user's role in WordPress, is the string I use for *role* case sensitive? For example, should I be using

```
wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'Editor' ) )
```

or

```
wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'editor' ) )
```

Or doesn't case matter in this situation?

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, case matters.

Some details: if you inspect WP_User::set_role() in /wp-includes/capabilities.php you will notice that there is no sanitization executed on the $role variable. And because PHP array keys are case-sensitive, "Editor" and "editor" would reference two different roles.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So with reference to the default roles that come as standard in WordPress, is it 'Editor' or 'editor'? Could you point me towards the file where the default roles are set?

Comment: The lowercase 'editor' is more accurate in your case. The capitalized "Editor" is the label of the role, which is used for presentation purposes. In answer to your question, you can locate the creation of the default roles in /wp-admin/includes/schema.php, line 607:611 (in the latest WP version).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer and follow up. +1 from me